# How to get all the users/groups who have access to a table and columns they have access

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a way where I could get all the users/groups/service account who has access to a table and columns they have access to in that table?

I did get only users for a project level but not for tables.

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import googleapiclient.discovery

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    filename='.../key.json',
    scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'])

service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('cloudresourcemanager', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

response = service.projects().getIamPolicy(resource='test-project', body={}).execute()

print(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use information schema to retrieve the information. see example below

```
SELECT * FROM myproject.`region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.OBJECT_PRIVILEGES
WHERE object_name = "mydataset";
```

Here Object Name can be table name too

See documentation link [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-object-privileges)

Hope this helps.

Comment: this is not giving all the users who have access to the table. @Bihag kashikar

Comment: Hi there, these views will not give inherited bindings, may be these are the ones that is not shown

Comment: anyway i could get those inherited bindings?